# Java pattern to match any character except exclamatory symbol

Tags: java, regex

I have a data stream and I want to grab only those strings that match the pattern. I have looked at other examples but mine gets bit trickier as it includes exclamation marks.

Here is a sample data

```
!P    this is a test !!
```

my end sequence is a !! and start sequence is !P. I want to grab the entire string above using pattern matcher. I am able to grab this data using the following pattern

```
Pattern.compile("!U[^!]*!!", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

using

```
[^!]*
```

I am filtering if there are cases like this:

```
!P this should not come !P this should come !!
```

But [^!]* is only for single character, I want to make sure i filter by !P and make sure I get only valid patterns that start with !P and end with !! eliminating invalid start and stops.

I want to filter the cases like follows:

```
!P this should come !! this should not come !!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this **negative lookahead** based regex:

```
!P(?:(?!![P!]).)*!!
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV0dO7/4)

Here `(?:(?!![P!]).)*` will match anything but `!P` or `!!` between start and end tokens.

Comment: Yes this works. But sorry I forgot to mention another thing too......I do also want to filter end sequences that occur in between like !P this should come !! this should not come !!, this should only return !P this should come !!